# Remove Thousands Separator on Negative Integer

Tags: c#, string, numbers, int

I would like to convert a string that is a negative number with thousand separator to integer.
I previously ran this code:

```
int ans = int.Parse(txtInt, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

But it produces a run-time error for negative number.

Any ideas on how to get the integer on a number string that has negative possibility?

Comment: What is the value of `txtInt` and what is your `CurrentCulture`?

Comment: A possibility negative number with thousand separator, let say `-10,000`. I use default CurrentCulture

Comment: It should work, perhaps your current culture uses a different thousand separator than the input string, use `int.Parse(txtInt, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes it supposed to work, but actually it works with positive integer with the same thousand separator format

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to use [`NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberstyles.aspx) also like;

```
int ans = int.Parse(txtInt, NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

Without this member, your string can have *only* your current culture thousand separator except digits. With this member, you can also specify your string can have your current culture negative or positive sign as well in leading position.

Of course this will work only if you use [`NegativeSign`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.numberformatinfo.negativesign.aspx) of your [`CurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You can allow leading signs by setting the `AllowLeadingSign` flag like so:

```
int ans = int.Parse(txtInt, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowThousands|System.Globalization.NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign);
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer shree.. I really appreciate it :) +1